# Find an existing id object in post web service bill

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to find an existing id object when I post a bill, but I don't know how find it to save the bill. I want it works from back end and front end.

This is my bill model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const billSchema = new Schema({
  number: Number,
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  type: String,
  local: String,
  client: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "clients"
  },
  provider: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "providers"
  },
  detail: [
    {
      quantity: Number,
      product: {
        code: Number,
        name: String,
        price: Number
      },
      undertotal: Number
    }
  ],
  total: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("bills", billSchema);
```

And this is my post service:

```
app.post("/api/bills", async (req, res) => {
  const { number, type, local, detail, total } = req.body;

  let existingClient = await Client.findById(Client._id);

  if (!existingClient) {
    return res.status(404).json({
      message: "not found client"
    });
  }

  let existingProvider = await Provider.findById(Provider._id);

  if (!existingProvider) {
    return res.status(404).json({
      message: "not found provider"
    });
  }

  if (
    !existingClient._id ||
    (existingClient._id &&
      mongoose.Types.ObjectId() ===
        (await Client.findById(existingClient._id).select("_id")))
  ) {
    const clientId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
    this.existingClient._id = clientId;
  }

  if (
    !existingProvider._id ||
    (existingProvider._id &&
      mongoose.Types.ObjectId() ===
        (await Provider.findById(existingProvider._id).select("_id")))
  ) {
    const providerId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
    this.existingProvider._id = providerId;
  }

  const bill = new Bill({
    number,
    date: new Date(),
    type,
    local,
    client: clientId,
    provider: providerId,
    detail,
    total
  });

  try {
    let newBill = await bill.save();
    res.status(201).send(newBill);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.name === "MongoError") {
      res.status(409).send(err.message);
    }
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});
```

The expected output is bill saved with client and provider ids but real output is an error message saying "cannot read property _id of undefined"

What is wrong?

Comment: The error message, for what line of your code applies. **_id** property is mentioned on several lines.

Comment: Yes. I only want to save an existing object id from a relationship in other object, in this case bill is object I want save and client and provider are my relationships. Bill object has got client and provider like relationships. In my bill post route I want to save a bill with client id and provider id like refs mongoose schemas. I don't know how I've got to define client id and provider id in bill post route.

Comment: In console, when you see the error it writes a line number where this error occurred. I want you to point out that line, in your question. Example: **the error occurs on line "let existingClient = await Client.findById(Client._id);"**.

Comment: I believe what's error. I'm not passing relationships ids like parameters on post route. And from client side I've got use the function window.location.replace and specify what url I gonna use to replace old url